# Launching a website using Javascript from Selenium doesn't work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to launch a webpage using Javascript using selenium web
I am using a chrome driver.

It wouldn't launch the site for reason. I made sure all the packages needed to called Javascript are included.

```html
import static org.junit.Assert.*; 

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; 

import org.junit.After;

import org.junit.AfterClass;

import org.junit.Before;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;

import org.junit.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import static org.junit.Assert.*; 

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 

import org.junit.After;

import org.junit.AfterClass;

import org.junit.Before;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;

import org.junit.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

 

 

public class JavaScriptSelenium {

      

       WebDriver achromeDriver;

       String abaseUrl;   

       private JavascriptExecutor js;

      

 

       @BeforeClass

       public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

       }

 

       @AfterClass

       public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {

       }

 

       @Before

       public void setUp() throws Exception {

 

             //abaseUrl = "http://letskodeit.teachable.com/pages/practice";

            

             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\ChromeDirver\\chromedriver.exe");

            

             achromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();

            

              achromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            

             achromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();;        

            

             System.out.println("setup completed");

            

       }

 

       @After

       public void tearDown() throws Exception {

       }

 

       @Test

       public void test() {           

             System.out.println("in Test");     

             js.executeScript("window.location ='https://www.google.com'");              

             try {

                    Thread.sleep(3000);

             } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();                 

             }          

             WebElement atextbox = (WebElement)js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('name')");           

             atextbox.sendKeys("Hello world"); 
       }

 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  How are you running the test?  There's an error?  Silent failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your @Test method, you have to assign the Driver to JavaScript executor, add

JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) achromeDriver; 
js.executeScript("window.location ='https://www.google.com'");